# Automation of NON GUI application using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have a web application running on tomcat.My application has no GUI.It processes files on some locations and persists values into the database and produce some output files on some locations.

I need to Automate testing of this application using selenium.This includes file creations, file movements between folders..etc.
My question is

1.Is it possible to automate this non-GUI application using selenium?How?
2.Is it possible to include these file creations, movements and DB values checking using selenium web driver

Comment: What makes it a "web application" if it has no GUI? Maybe it's a web *service* if it handles HTTP requests, but according to your description it only processes files and a database. Please clarify.

Comment: It is a mule application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the *Home Page* of [**Selenium**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/01_introducing_selenium.jsp#introducing-selenium) it is clearly mentioned that :

> Selenium is the most widely-used open source solution in building **Test Automation** for **Web Applications**. The suite of tools provided by *Selenium* results in a rich set of testing functions specifically catering to the needs of testing of web applications of all types. These operations are flexible and allows many options for locating UI elements and comparing expected test results against actual application behavior.

As your *Automation Testing* requirement is :

- File Creation
- File Movements between folders

It seems **Selenium** may not be the appropiate tool.

A framework built through **Perl** or **Python** may better cater to your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium is created to automate test on UI. You can use on Page Object Model or directly on findelement(or findelements) but you have to give a locator attribute which it can be [according to selenium documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html):

`id
name
xpath
link_text
partial_link_text
tag_name
class_name
css_selector`

So if you have these locators yes, but if you don't, Selenium is not suiting for this task. Maybe you looking for an API tester, Unit tester or what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: According to the question, the application does not have a GUI, so no locator is relevant whatsoever, let alone a Page Object Model.

Comment: irrelevant answer